# IPTables/Masquerade, making Linux kernel to see duplicate packets

Tags: iptables

Will this rules make kernel to see the same packet at least twice?

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE                                                                   
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Found the stuff in a forgotten config file. A remark about option "-d 0/0" was also there, did this option makes sense when certain log targets are used in iptables - to avoid incorrect traffic calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, packets will not be seen twice. Only one of those two `iptables` rules will ever match a given packet, since a packet cannot exit the system by two different network interfaces at the same time. The routing algorithm always selects (at most) one output interface.

Answer (score -1):

`-o` specifies that a particular packet is to be *tested* for its interface, it does not specify that a packet is to *leave* by that interface. (The latter would be routing and is controlled by `ip route`.)